# CodeIgniter 2 HTTP Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, authentication, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to set up a very basic HTTP auth for an admin directory on my site built with CodeIgniter 2.

I've tried the suggestions here http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/141775/ but it still doesn't seem to work.

Help?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CodeIgniter - this is something with your server setup. You need to post additional details regarding your server and the attempt with both .htaccess and .htpasswd - in other words; instead of refering to a thread you are working from, tell us what you have tried and how.

Comment: PHP can handle this, he's not asking a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my REST Server library:

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L697

I've written code to protect my API's with basic and digest. You could easily reuse this stuff for your admin panel.